# Determining stream elevation points from SRTM raster with stream lines vector?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, 3d-analyst, srtm

I should determine elevation points of some streams. I have SRTM raster and stream vectors.

Which tools can solve this problem in ArcGIS 9.3?

Comment: You have told us what version you have, but what license level do you have? Specifically, do you have access to the Spatial or 3D Analyst extensions?

Comment: Yes, i have 3D Analyst extension.

Answer (score 1):

1) [feature vertices to points](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Feature%20Vertices%20to%20Points%20%28Data%20Management%29) to get some points along your stream
 (if you don't have ArcInfo, you can use ET Geowizard)

2) [extract value to point](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=extract_values_to_points) ta extract the value of the DEM for each point.